# Android Facebook sdk can't handle device rotation properly?

Tags: android, facebook

I'd like to authenticate my users using the Facebook SSO service. I managed to handle basic login with the official Android Facebook sdk, which was quite painless, but it seems that the sdk just can't handle device rotation - at least I couldn't find a way to get it work correctly.

The auth code:

```
loginButtonFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do FB login
                facebook.authorize(LoginActivity.this, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Facebook login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.d(TAG, "FACEBOOK LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
                        //loginFB(facebook.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "FacebookError:" +error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

My Activity also needs to handle the result from the FB login activity:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

This works, but the facebook.authorize(...) method need a reference for my current Activity, so it can do a callback later. But if the device is rotated when the user is in the facebook authorization Activity, my previous Activity gets destroyed. So after the user authorizes my app., I don't get the callback about this.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest file under your activity name just add the following line

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

inside your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ................
}
```

Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Don't use it unless you're sure what you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/1118475

Answer (score 1):

I usually hate recommending this, but the `Activity` that Facebook uses can be locked to portrait without any negative consequences. All it does is show an indefinite `ProgressBar`.

Check your manifest for the activity with the name `com.facebook.LoginActivity` and make sure it has the following properties:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```