# Activity restart issue

Tags: android, orientation

I have activity in my application and i have set **android:configChanges="orientation"** in my menifest file like this :

```
 <activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and method to handle it :

```
@Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
      Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
```

In most google search i saw that it is saying it will prevent restarting my activty but it is starting with orientation changed.I put a System.out.... inside **onCreate()** it is printing with every orientation change that means it geting started.Any help why it is happening or am i wrong somewhere ?

Comment: "If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations." - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @appserv nothing like that i have minimum 4 and target as 8

Comment: plz see this post maybe help full:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: @imrankhan I am already seeing that but i have some code that need activity instance as "this" that i cant use inside that Application class or can i ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller : try after adding this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"></uses-permission>`. every thing is right in your code.

Comment: @imrankhan I added this permission after <application></application> tag.But it is not working.

Comment: Do you have separate layouts for landscape and portrait?

Comment: @AndroidKiller : can u tell me why it's not working without keyboardHidden? bez it's working on my end without keyboardHidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

On orientation it will not restart the activity

Comment: thanks but am not using same thing ? i dont want keyboardhidden attribute so i am not using it.

Comment: it is working.I tried it and it is working.Can you tell me why ? because "KeyBoardGidden" nothing to do with it. right ?

Comment: Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation), and you can accept my answer if it works for you