# Login orientation change

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have problem with android login dialog. I don't want to set `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` parameter in Manifest because it isn't good android programming practice. On the other hand on orientation change without it applicaction crushes. Is there any good solution in this situation or alternative?

Comment: Not sure if this'll be of much use, but try going through 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Comment: Because of all the problems with this parameter I don't want to use it :)

Comment: @ania Then there must be something causing the crash. Can you share the stack trace and/or code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I did have similar problems and also did not want to set `android:configChanges`. I basically nailed the issue down to `onSaveInstance(Bundle outstate)`. Apparently calling `Session.saveSession()` was dying because my bundle was not "serializable" for whatever reason...