# How to crop camera images for portrait view in Android version 3.0+?

Tags: android, image-processing

I have used this [link](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop) to crop image. It worked well for Android 2.3.3 and older ones. I have faced the problem in using this source code for Android 3.0+.

The problem is if I take the photo from the gallery, it crops normally. But if I take a picture on the device then I have got Toast message *"unable to crop image"*. I'm doing testing on Samsung GALAXY S II.
I  have face problem on orientation change .. This code working well for landscape but i have face problem in portrait view.

Comment: what problem you face in 3.0?

Comment: I used the same code and it works fine at my end with Android 4.0.3(ICS).

Comment: i have got Toast message "unable to crop image" i m doing testing on Samsung GALAXY S II @LalitPoptani

Comment: this problem came when i have use camera image fro cropping @VineetShukla

Comment: I used both gallery and camera image and both are working fine. Debug at your end.

Comment: The following [link](http://androidfragments.blogspot.in/2012/02/loading-bitmaps-from-gallery.html) may helps you in solving your issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have got the answer i thing problem in change orientation . this is solve by using `android:configChanges="orientation"`
in manifest file

Comment: This is definitely not the solution... you are definitely implementing your app incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexLockwood i have use this solution then this is work fine dear

Comment: [**`onConfigurationChanged` is nothing more than a bandaid**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/844882)

Comment: i have Got answer .. i have problem in orientation change . thanks for reply.. your comment useful for me. @Vineet Shukla