# All fragments visible after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have a problem with fragments when my device is rotate:
i have 5 fragments:

1. Menu is the first fragment, when activity start, it is launched.
2. AddUser (simple fragment that i can see when i press a button in menu fragment)
3. DetailApp (simple fragment that i can see when i press a button in menu fragment)
4. DetailUser (simple fragment that i can see when i press a button in menu fragment)
5. ListUser (ListFragment that i can see when i press a button in menu fragment)

When i start my activity in vertical mode, i can see correctly my fragments, when i rotate my smartphone, i can see.. all fragments overlapping!
if i launch ListUser i have:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x... for fragment ...
```

when start my Menu fragments:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager);
```

this is oncreate

```
// Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
// the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
    // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
    // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
    // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    }

    //first frame show a menu
    Menu firstFragment = new Menu();

    // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
    // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
    firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();    
    }
```

fragment container at start is void..

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

when i press a button and one of fragments start:

```
@Override
public void onDetailApp(int position) {
// The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
// Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
DetailApp appFrag = (DetailApp)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailapp_fragment);

if (appFrag != null) {
    // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

    // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
    appFrag.updateAppointmentView(position);

} else {
    // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

    // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
    DetailApp newFragment = new DetailApp();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DetailApp.ARG_APPOINTMENT, position);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

this is onCreateView from DetailUser, AddUser, DetailApp:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_adduser, container, false);
}
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

by

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

99% of times it solves duplication issues.

Comment: but why i can see all fragments if nobody calls it?

Comment: if you stop your code before it returns on that line `if (savedInstanceState != null) {` and check the contents (Debug perspective), you'll see that all the fragments state is stored there and the system is re-creating them inside the super.onCreate(). So, you're not calling it, but the system is.

Comment: This does not solve the problem - it also just covers it up by using replace instead of add. So you're suggesting the OP never uses add? What if he needs to though? Not a good solution :/ !

Answer (score -1):

i add this on my Manifest activity and override onConfigurationChanged:
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.map.manager.ManagerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_manager" >
    </activity>
```

and i have no more problems! i can see correctly layout vertical and horizontal (when i rotate the smartphone). 
but i found this: [why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation)
must i put in "blacklist" all possible configuration change? locale touchscreen screenSize etc?

Comment: You're not dealing with the problem, you're just covering it up. The proper way would be to handle configuration changes, not trying to suppress them. From experience I can say: We had phones that totally ignored the configChanges settings, hence dealing with the config changes was the only chance to maintain consistent behavior across different phones