# Android CheckedTextView state

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I've following problem:
I've create custom Android class for `CheckedTextView`:

```
public class CustomCheckedTextView extends CheckedTextView {
    public CustomCheckedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
                this.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((CheckedTextView) v) .toggle();
                        if (isChecked()){
                            setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else {
                            setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        }

            }) ;
        }
}
```

And use it in main activity as following:

```
 LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
 final CustomCheckedTextView checkedTV = new CustomCheckedTextView(this);
 llayout.addView(checkedTV)
```

So I can tap on `CustomCheckedTextView` and background will be Green. But when I rotate phone background become white again. Why it's happens?

Comment: when you're rotating device `onResume()` is called so you can write code in that also..

Comment: @juned so I need to check all states in some array, and set them back after each rotation? Is there any another solution?

Comment: you can go with blganesh101's answer :)

Comment: while blganes101's answer will do the trick in 80%, sometimes things will go terribly wrong, for reason google states that it should be used as last option possible and to prefer savedInstanceState and restoreInstanceState.. check answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: [Documentation states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html): Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use configChanges for this.  Having an understanding of why it happens and how to save state is very important.  Please read the [documentation on this topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).