# android configChange:orientation and manifest does not work

Tags: android

I have used a Web view. which loads webpage. When i orientation is changed it reloads. I want to stop reloading. I did following change in manifest XML File. 
It works in android 2.2 but not in android 4.0. I am a beginner can any one provide solution.

My Manifest.xml is;

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="application.eag"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you should not use it, and let android do its work. Still if you want to use you have to add orientation|screenSize

Comment: " I did following change in manifest XML File" .Where you have mentioned the changes?

Comment: @user2012 Please check the title. `I did following change in manifest XML File` refers to `android configChange:orientation` in the title. I too tried to place a comment like u.... :)

Comment: @AvadhaniY: My mistake.Thanks for pointing out.Well it should work then.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Use `screenSize` for newly version. `orientation` might not be supported in some version, need to use `screenSize` for `configChanges`

Comment: thanks Avadhani Y for your prompt reply, i made the changes as you mentioned. In eclipse I am getting error "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden')." Do i have to add anything else?

Comment: Inside the `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest`, By the way, what are the values u have given for `android:minSdkVersion`, `android:targetSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?? use this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>` for `android:minSdkVersion` give the value whatever u want

Comment: Still No success. Here eclipse is not allowing me to enter value "orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: where are you adding. You have to add inside your `activity` tag.

Comment: yes i am adding it in activity tag only. as follows  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I have added the same above lines in my manifest and i am not getting any errors... Can u please show me ur complete manifest file by editing your question???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32819/discussion-between-manojmore-and-avadhani-y)

Comment: for me i had to add uiMode along with these config changes to make it work!!

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like the following and it works for me.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: Here eclipse is not allowing me to enter value "orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

Made changes as answered by Avadhani Y
1) Added following in manifest

```
<activity
android:name=".ActivityName"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

2) changed manifest as

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

3) in project.properties set the following value

```
# Project target.
target=android-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your activity like this ...

```
 <activity
        android:name=".UserLoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of these to work, but then I got it (not sure what was going on but thought I'd elaborate on other answers to save people time).  I found the below to work for my app (1 line in your manifest INSIDE the  tag, for the activity you want this behavior for.  I also discovered it completely depends on your app on what you need here.  For a complete list see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

And by 'doesn't work', I mean the onDestroy() method got called every time I rotated my device.  See [Why not use always android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation) for reasons you likely shouldn't use this.

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        >
```