# CharSequence Restarts After Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I have a CharSequence  which displays a sequence of text after each imageview click however the CharSequence seems to restart if the orientation is changed mid sequence.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

On an orientation change the activity is restarted,  and the inCreate() is called again. You have to take that in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

A small example of how to store and retrieve a value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isStarted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isStarted");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    isStarted = true;
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("isStarted", isStarted);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

For more information and methods: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

using android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"> resolved the issue

Comment: Please no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation