# Android :Save View Pager State

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to save view pager state, in order to avoid creating fragments once again on orientation change. Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

I tried below stuff, but not sure how it will work...

```
    int pagerId = 0;

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        DialerPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new DialerPagerAdapter(fm);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getInt("tab") != -1) {
               mPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab"));
                pagerId=savedInstanceState.getInt("pagerState");
            }
        }
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
        if (pagerId != -1 ){
            mPager.setId(pagerId);
        }else{
            pagerId=mPager.getId();
        }
        mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
```

in saveInstanceState I am doing below stuff

```
outState.putInt("pagerState" , mPager.getId() );
```

Thanks 
Venkatraman

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivityeThatContainsViewPager"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
/>
```

Comment: Not good advice in my opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Comment: configChanges is basically a hack and should only really be used as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

Example saving string in shared preferences and retrieve it again anywhere in your app.

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PreferencesData.saveString(context, "mynote", "Sherlock is weird");
// retrieve
String note = PreferencesData.getString(context, "mynote", "");
```

Use this to save the string on pause, and recreate it in onCreate, or where ever you need the information

The same method can easily be used for other simple types.

For your use case:

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    DialerPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new DialerPagerAdapter(fm);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getInt("tab") != -1) {
           // this could also be saved with PreferencesData
           // but if you want the app to start at the first
           // tab when device is restarted or recreated, this is fine.
           mPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab")); 
        }
    }

    // defaults to 0 if first startup after install
    int pagerId = PreferencesData.getInt(this, "pagerId", 0);
    mPager.setId(pagerId);

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
```

And in onPause()

```
PreferencesData.saveInt(this, "pagerId", mPager.getId());
```

Comment: whoops been too fast pasting code, corrected to string now, was mixed with some int-value code

Comment: What could be the value you are advising to save in preference?? can u  explain better...

Comment: will add example in a moment

Comment: Hi @cYrixmorten, I Tried your lines and I am getting white screen and none of my fragments are got launched. Suggest some other feasible solution

Comment: Can save the tab to preferences too but if something else is wrong with your code, I have no chance of helping. I simply know that this way of saving to shared preferences works for saving state.