# Sharedpreferences in ListAdapter

Tags: android

Is it possible to use sharedpreferences with a ListAdapter ?
  In my main activity I would like to set a flag that can be picked up in my listadapter
  Is this possbile ?

Regards

foud a solution meanwhile
Hello,
 I've found it ...

in the main activity onCreate

```
final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("refresh", false);
editor.commit();
```

when 'refresh' is pushed

```
// Set "refresh" to true
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("refresh", true);
editor.commit();
```

and in the listAdapter on GetView(own created, extend on SimpleAdapter)

```
// Get parent context
Context contextParent = parent.getContext();
// Get shared preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = contextParent.getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Refresh ?
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("refresh", false) == true) {
...
}
```

Comment: hello, meanwhile I've also found 'a' solution, is it possible to give an example on how you would do it ?

Comment: I simply use a helperclass with static methods, see my answer to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048693/android-save-view-pager-state/19048917#19048917][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048693/android-save-view-pager-state/19048917#19048917