# Performing an orientation change while an options menu is open causes a WindowLeaked exception. (API 10)

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-optionsmenu

I'm writing an app targeting **Android API 10 (Gingerbread 2.3.3)**.  If I rotate the device while the options menu is open I get a **`WindowLeaked`** **exception**.  Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

*The exception goes away if I target API level 11 or higher, but I need API 10 for this particular app.*

Exception log:

```
04-18 00:51:19.025  27934-27934/com.example.menuexample E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.menuexample.MenuExampleActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41df94a0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-768,156} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:672)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:879)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1630)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2010)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1704)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1695)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1987)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a very minimal Activity that will recreate the Exception:

```
package com.example.menuexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MenuExampleActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Give the app a simple menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_something"
          android:title="something" />
</menu>
```

And set the **minSdkVersion** to **10** in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Rotating the device with the options menu open will cause the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden
```

Then in your activity add this somewhere:

```
   @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls_port);
}
 if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls_port );
} 
}
```

I'm not quite sure why the error is being caused, though when I tested it does not throw the exception--I wouldn't call it a fix but more of a workaround.

The line in the manifest file prevents the activity from being restarted when the device is rotated. Then when you override `onConfigurationChanged()`, a method that's called when the device is rotated,  and since your're overriding it you have to specify the correct layout for portrait/orientation.

Note that `onConfigurationChanged()` may not just be called when the device is rotated--there are many others times this may be called, you can see the complete list [at the android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). As such, it may not be good to perform whatever is done in that method when, say, the locale (language) has changed. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation).

Also note that the without `android:configChanges` in your manifest the `onConfigurationChanged()` method does nothing.

Best of luck!

Comment: This works for me.  It does seem like a workaround, but I'll take that over an Exception.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is still an issue.  Is it a Java or android bug?  How the heck do you work around this without having to handle config changes yourself?  If only a option menu is open it throws the exception but is swallowed and the user does not see any problem.  But if a sub menu is also open and the device rotated, the app crashes.

Comment: . -edit-  crashes on Lenovo TB-X104F(android 8.1.0) but not on SM-N950U1 (android 9).  Also noticed that on the Lenovo, the sub menu and its parent are displayed while on the Samsung, the sub menu replaces the parent menu.