# onConfigurationChanged isn't called on screen rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, rotation

I have googled at bit and saw few people it had happened to them,

but i'm not sure how to fix this:

I have an android Activity and when i rotate my device

only `onCreate()` is called, no `onConfigurationChanged()`.

when does this happen?

my activity declaration from my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".reports.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" >
</uses-sdk>
```

Comment: Post the manifest declaration of your activity?

Comment: Please have a look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation)