# Fragment removes when Orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am using fragment in my application. When I change the orientation the fragment removes and my main activity gets visible from which I have added this fragment. below is the code -

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new ManageDataFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new DownloadFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new UserInfoFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new AboutAppFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new ShareAppFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        setTitle(menutitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

I am using this fragment from navigationDrawer like in Gmail application.
What should I do that my fragment remains even I change the orientation of device?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: where does this code go? `onCreate` ?

Comment: No. It's in onClickListener of navigationDrawer. Like in Gmail app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the accepted answer is the correct so I'm writing this one:

When replacing the fragment you should use the method [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) with three arguments so you can find your fragment later:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
```

Where `TAG_FRAGMENT` is some string tag.

Then in `onCreate` if the activity was restarted you can find your fragment and add it to the container:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
}
```

Comment: Yes, Its working. But I am facing another problem now that when I click on back button on fragment the activity through which I have added this fragment gets closed. I want to go to the activity when user clicks on back button on fragment. Is there any property for that?

Comment: You can use the method `addToBackStack` form the `FragmentTransaction`. More about navigation here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as mentioned above and I fixed it in the AndroidManifest by adding this:

```
 <activity
        ...
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|layoutDirection">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @unflagged.destination This is not a solution, it's more like a hack.Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Answer (score 0):

Probably should save position using onSaveInstanceState() and test the bundle argument to onCreate().