# Android integer xml resource value doesn't change when switching between portrait and landscape

Tags: android, android-resources, landscape-portrait

I using the following GradientDrawable as background for a RelativeLayout:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="@integer/my_value"
        android:endColor="#0FFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFF" />
</shape>
```

Then created a file called integers.xml in the **res\values** folder:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="my_value">90</integer>
</resources>
```

And another file with the same name under **res\values-land** folder:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="my_value">180</integer>
</resources>
```

**So when I rotate the device the gradient goes from bottom->top to right->left when running Android 2.3.3 (as expected) but when I test this on Android 4.4.4 the gradient angle does not change.**

I've also tried with:

```
<item name="my_value" format="float" type="dimen">90</integer>
```

but same result.

**Any ideas?**

**UPDATE:**

The RelativeLayout that uses the GradientDrawable exists in 2 different files:

1. res\layout\my_layout
2. res\layout-land\my_layout

res\layout-land\my_layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" >
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem happens only when rotating the device. If I start the activity with the device previously rotated then the gradient angle is properly set.

Comment: Are you using them the same way? Inside an xml layout, used by an Activity?

Comment: There's just one little thing I forgot to mention. The RelativeLayout that I mentioned exists in 2 layout files. One for portrait and another one for landscape.

Comment: Is this really needed to have this dimension in the resources?

Comment: Not really but I wanted to avoid having to create 2 different drawables. It works fine in the emulator running API 10 but fails to change on device running API 19

Comment: How do you define the activity(from where you are calling this) in your manifest? Do you allow it to redraw on orientation change?

Comment: 2 drawable vs 2 resources item... But its weired indeed

Comment: @ShobhitPuri in parent activity I've only added android:launchMode="singleTop" then the usual name, label and logo attributes.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I'm starting to think it's some kind of optimization in newer android versions where it is probably reusing drawables or something.

Comment: @SantiagoAceñolaza have you tried putting the values in the `values-v19-land`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin just tried but same behavior. Good thinking anyways! I might be thinking this the wrong way if nobody has faced this problem before...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I guess I get it because I declared configuration changes in manifest file. I realized this possible cause after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation/7990543#7990543

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround would be tu use directly two different shapes:

1. one for the portrait mode

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <gradient
           android:angle="90"
           android:endColor="#0FFF"
           android:startColor="#FFFF" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. one for the landscape mode

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <gradient
           android:angle="180"
           android:endColor="#0FFF"
           android:startColor="#FFFF" />
   </shape>
   ```