# Stopping onCreate being executed on screen rotation in Android

Tags: android

I have an activity with 4 elements. A spinner containing a list of dates, a spinner containing a list of hours, a button and a list view. The spinner's selected items are used to form a web service URL which is called when the button is clicked and the response is shown in the list view.

The issue is if the user views the app in portrait mode, chooses a date, chooses an hour and clicks the button, the response of the web service call is shown in the list view however, if the device is rotated to landscape then the data in the list view is gone (because in order to get it there a button click is needed).

I understand that onCreate is called when the screen is rotated. I do not want to force the orientation so is there any way I can stop the list view being cleared? Note that the selected values in my spinners remain the same after rotation, it is just the response in the list view that is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to prevent activity recreation  put this in you AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

Read this for more info - [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: This is really not a good idea, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Answer (score 0):

You can force activity screen orientation in `AndroidManifest.xml` by setting `screenOrientation` property:

```
<activity android:name=".FooActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

This is a half-solution. If you want to handle screen rotation, you should save and restore activity state. This is the major, royal **PITA** in any Android application I've seen.

The problem is, that your application logic is mixed with view code, which can be destroyed at any moment. Perfect combination, Google! It's like running a function that can disappear during execution. :)

To counter this sorry design decision you may want to move your application logic to service, which will not be destroyed when screen rotates. This 2-layer design is closer to universally accepted MVC pattern, as you separate your logic from your view. Service stays, activity attaches and detaches from service on demand, making screen rotation handling a breeze.

If you're dealing with webservices, do not try to invent your own solution for this. There is couple of nice libraries to handle this nicely, such as `RoboSpice` and you'll probably never come with any quick solution that is as good as those libs. Give it a try.

Also, watch this Google I/O video about developing Android REST client applications: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Answer (score 0):

Have your button set a static class variable, or shared preference. Then, call a method that reads that value, and does what you want. THEN, put a call to that same method, in onResume(), possibly based on a condition... I think that's what's worked for me. When you come back from configuration change or kill, onResume() should re-do whatever you had last done.