# Save the position of scrollview when the orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

These is my layout:

[image: detail layout]

I need to save the scrolling position when the orientation changes. for example if the screen shows layout starting from middle name in portrait mode,it should start from same in the landscape mode.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

You If your activity is not changing anything on rotation you can use 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in manifest file within this particular activity. But this is clearly workaround and not a proper solution.

**Note:**

*If you need to use different views for landscape and portraits or if you need to use different views for different devices, One should use bundle and save data onsaveinstancestate and retrieve the data in oncreate. This method stops to recreate the activity and activity assumes that things will be handled by the user himself/herself.*

Comment: This is not a good solution if you have different Views for landscape and portrait, since neither the Activity nor the Fragment will recreate its Views using this configuration. You might also get a weird looking Action Bar.

Comment: Yes Johan, Agreed and modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on config changes. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/3113823

Comment: This is just a workaround and it is not the proper solution how to do that.

Comment: Same is written in note bro

Comment: Wow, I have never seen any marked answer having gotten this many down-votes.

Comment: Clearly not the best way.

Answer (score 68):

Just set **android:id** on your scrolling element. Your view will save its scrolling position automatically.

Code from View.java:15554

```
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    if (mID != NO_ID && (mViewFlags & SAVE_DISABLED_MASK) == 0) {
        mPrivateFlags &= ~PFLAG_SAVE_STATE_CALLED;
        Parcelable state = onSaveInstanceState();
        if ((mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_SAVE_STATE_CALLED) == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Derived class did not call super.onSaveInstanceState()");
        }
        if (state != null) {
            // Log.i("View", "Freezing #" + Integer.toHexString(mID)
            // + ": " + state);
            container.put(mID, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I think this is the most common reason why scrollviews dont restore their position

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Although posting code from View.java is a little confusing in this context.

Comment: This did not work for me when having a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` but the solution of Umesh Clauhan below worked.

Comment: Wow! mindblowing solution and this just works  if you are restoring the view state. 
 But this certainly is not a solution when, views have to be recreated and shown to the user like nothing happened.

Answer (score 45):

To save and restore the scroll position of a ScrollView when the phone orientation changes you can do the following:
Save the current position in the onSaveInstanceState method:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putIntArray("ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION",
            new int[]{ mScrollView.getScrollX(), mScrollView.getScrollY()});
}
```

Then restore the position in the onRestoreInstanceState method. Note that we need to post a Runnable to the ScrollView to get this to work:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final int[] position = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION");
    if(position != null)
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1]);
            }
        });
}
```

Found this solution on google. Credit goes to Original Coder. :)

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: This is not necessary, you ONLY need to set an ID on your ScrollView (see actual answer...)

Comment: Try adding this offset to get exact position when changing from vertical to horizontal orientation: `mScrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1] + getScreenWidth()/4);`

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung tablet, I didn't have to add as much code (just the call to the superclass). Also, I already had a name on the ListView.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter search string here" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSearch"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_text"/>

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_books"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_text"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android OS keeps the UI state when config changes or activity gets killed because of low memory. This includes but is not limited to the `RecyclerView` scroll position and string inside the `EditText`.

However, you must set the **UNIQUE** id `android:id` to let Android OS handle this.

Answer (score -1):

refer these  to persist the scroll position and scroll after orientation change.

https://asishinwp.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/save-scrollview-position-resume-scrollview-from-that-position/

https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/how-to-save-the-position-of-a-scrollview-when-the-orientation-changes-in-android/

Comment: Don't post link only answers. The content in the links may change or the link may stop working. Instead include the relevant content in your answer and provide links for attribution or further reading

Answer (score -5):

Do this in manifest..

```
  <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
  </activity>
```