# onSaveInstanceState null in Fragment everytime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I search everywhere and for the solution but not find it, I need some help.

I have an app that has Two activity's, Activity A and Activity B, but B have fragments, the first fragment from B, have an important data that I don't want to lose when the user press back when going to Activity A.

My problem is this every time I'm back to Activity A and go to B, my Data go empty because android clear it, so I made some search and changes on the code and still not find the solution. Now my code :

**ACTIVITY A**

```
  fbReceive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OmniActivity.class));

            }
        });
```

I call B from this line and when they go to B this is the code :

**ACTIVITY B**

```
public class OmniActivity extends BaseActivity {

private View parent_view;

private TabLayout tab_layout;

FragmentOmni fragmentOmni     = new FragmentOmni();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_omni_om);
    parent_view = findViewById(R.id.container);

    Tools.setSystemBarColor(this, R.color.new_purple_O200);

    openFragment(fragmentOmni);

    initToolbar();
    initComponent();

}

public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment, fragment.getTag());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

    private void initToolbar() {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Voltar");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(OmniActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
    });

}
```

And when the application executes OpenFragment() they go to this code from Fragment :

**FRAGMENT A**

```
public class FragmentOmni extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
MDOmniturn controller;


List<HashMap<String, String>> listproduct;
private ArrayList<Product> producttypelist;
Product tpobjproduct;
private ActionMode actionMode;
private ActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;


private ListProductAdapter lpAdapter;

private NestedScrollView nested_scroll_view;

private ImageButton bt_toggle_input;
private Button      bt_hide_input;
private View        lyt_expand_input;

EditText edOmni, edMani,edEan ;

LinearLayout layoutNoResult;

Handler time;
TextWatcher textexample;


private ProgressBar progressBarProduct;

LinearLayout linearLayout;


public FragmentOmni() {
}

public static FragmentOmni newInstance() {
    FragmentOmni fragment = new FragmentOmni();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){

        producttypelist = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");

    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omni, container, false);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("list", producttypelist);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        producttypelist = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");

    }


    initexpand(view);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);

    edOmni = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edOmni);
    edMani = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edBManifesto);
    edEan  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edEan);

    progressBarProduct = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarProduct);

    layoutNoResult = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutNoResult);
    recyclerView   = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new LineItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    controller      = new MDOmniturn(getActivity());
    producttypelist = new ArrayList<>();
    listproduct     = new ArrayList<>();

    addListenerTextChange(edOmni);

    //set data and list adapter
    lpAdapter = new ListProductAdapter(getActivity(), producttypelist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(lpAdapter);
    lpAdapter.setOnClickListener(new ListProductAdapter.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, Product obj, int pos) {

            if (lpAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 0) {

                enableActionMode(pos);

            } else {

                // read the inbox which removes bold from the row
                Product product = lpAdapter.getItem(pos);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Read: " + product.prd_description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, Product obj, int pos) {
            enableActionMode(pos);
        }
    });

    actionModeCallback = new ActionModeCallback();

}
```

The savedInstanceState from FRAGMENT A always go NULL, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to the following order

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("list", producttypelist);    
}
```

It might be possible you are expecting data during the wrong state too.
For example, the `savedInstanceState` will always be `null` the first time an Activity is started which also points to your fragment, but may be `non-null` if an Activity is destroyed during rotation, because `onCreate` is called each time activity starts or restarts.

This line `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` is unnecessary. You can save the fragment state on its `onStop()` and `onPause()` and restore `onResume()` and `onCreate()`.

You can remove the `onBackPressed()` in Activity B now

---

---

Alternatively, you can use Shared Preferences. When exiting the application, (`onBackPressed`, `onPause` ...) save the item you want. For Example the high score of a game.

```
 activity.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("score", highScore).apply();
```

And retrieving the score would be:

```
int value = activity.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("score", 0);
```

Comment: I put but nothing happens, always go null when he passes the validation on onViewCreated from the Fragment.

Comment: When I press back on my Activity B, the Activity is not destroyed I make a debug for it, and put a log in onDestroy function from Activity B never got destroyed.


I put this function  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

to prevent this, you know? I want just to save the data from the Fragment when the user goes to another activity and when he goes back to Activity A that have Fragment A he sees the old data.

Comment: @Wavrik adding more content to the answer

Comment: Hi Lucem, thank you for your help.

I see in this thread from stack overflow that is not a good practice savedInstanceState to persistence data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

And must do what you said, OnPause() or OnResume() but how I do that?

If go to OnPause and my variable will lost? after change activity how I will restore it? Another thing, I don't want the Shared Preference solution.

Comment: Its actually the simpler way to go for. Would you like me to edit the answer with the alternative? @Wavrik

Comment: I will love Lucem.

Shared Preference is the only way?

Comment: One more question Lucem. I just use onSaveInstanceState when the orientation change? Is not for data persistence when i change the activity?

Comment: Okay, then you can save the data stil with the instance. look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208086/save-the-position-of-scrollview-when-the-orientation-changes#answer-29208325