# Memory leaks with MapView in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've already checked a bunch of other questions but none of the solutions have worked, I'm not using googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) so thats not the problem.

The adapter that I am loading the MapView in is located [here](https://github.com/caman9119/SpaceLaunchNow/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/me/calebjones/spacelaunchnow/content/adapter/LaunchBigAdapter.java).

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //TODO: Allow user to update this 1-normal 2-satellite 3-Terrain
        MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);

        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

        googleMap.setMapType(1);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        // If we have map data, update the map content.
        if (mMapLocation != null) {
            updateMapContents();
        }
    }
```

The map loads fine and functions, I'm just getting Out of Memory errors after orientation changes.

Heres the output of LeakCanary:

In me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.debug:1.0.0-DEBUG:28.
* me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.MainActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT maps.dz.af$a.f
* references maps.dz.af.k
* references maps.dg.p.mParent
* references android.widget.FrameLayout.mParent
* references com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.mContext
* leaks me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.MainActivity instance

- Retaining: 2.3 KB.
- Reference Key: 9007ff6a-0072-49ce-b8cc-afc17cb19a76
- Device: motorola google Nexus 6 shamu
- Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.4-beta1 02804f3
- Durations: watch=5791ms, gc=156ms, heap dump=11974ms, analysis=85902ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding this to your manifest, in the activity tag?

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Wow, really? That worked. Do you have some reading material for explaining what's going on with that?

Comment: Even having solved your problem, you shouldn't use this solution for every case. It is well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Comment: Great, thats informative. Its definitely a bandaid though, I'm able to reproduce the memory leak when making other configuration changes unrelated...however those should be less frequent to a user.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, but your solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are GoogleMap in your ViewHolder. You should override method onViewRecycled and clean memory:

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(FriendViewHolder holder) {
if (holder.gMap != null) {
        holder.gMap.clear();
        holder.gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    }
}
```