# Keyboard hides on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-orientation, window-soft-input-mode

Similar question has already appeared several times, but I have found strange regularity which I think should not occur.

There is `Activity` with `EditText` in its layout. When user clicks on that field, soft input appears. With flag `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"` added to `AndroidManifest`, everything works as expected on device orientation changes - keyboard retains its state. But when there is `Fragment` on top of that `Activity` and `EditText` is located in the `Fragment` it does not work. I assume that flag on `AndroidManifest` is skipped in this case (flag covers only `Activity`), and during orientation changes keyboard disappears.

I did not found clean solution for retaining keyboard state on orientation change. I saw solution with manually showing keyboard on `onActivityCreated()`, but I do not like it as it requires to hold keyboard visibility state on some variable in object which survives orientation changes.
What I found is that if there is `EditText` in `Activity`, even when user does not touch it, and it is not focused, keyboard retains its state, which is totally unexpected.

I cannot remove `Fragment` and rely only on `Activity` because `Fragments` are used in `ViewPager`. But I have checked that this happens also when the `Fragment` is directly attached to the `Activity`.

I also found that all applications I've checked, solved that problem somehow.

Is there a clean solution for retaining keyboard state on orientation changes with fragments?

Edit: I also dislike the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your activity in manifest

> android:configChanges="orientation"

It's not perfect but you may try it

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have rejected this idea at the beginning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/1888738. Also android:configChanges works only with "orientation|screenSize" flags on post Honeycomb devices.