# How to prevent EditText contents from being copied when Android screen orientation changes

Tags: java, android

I have some `Activity` code that goes like this:

```
void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(...);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(...);
    et.setEditableFactory(new Editable.Factory() {
        @Override public Editable newEditable(CharSequence source) {
            return (Editable) source;
        }
    });
    et.setText(new MySpannableStringBuilderSubclass("foo"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

Essentially, I want to have the backing text for an `EditText` be a custom class I created, `MySpannableStringBuilderSubclass`. The call to `setEditableFactory` ensures that `setText` doesn't copy the contents of my subclass into a `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Everything above works fine provided the phone doesn't change screen orientation; `getText().getClass().getSimpleName()` returns `MySpannableStringBuilderSubclass` as it should. However, if I change the phone's orientation to landscape, the activity is destroyed/re-created. When I call `findViewById`, the returned `EditText` already has the text "foo", but `getText().getClass().getSimpleName()` is `SpannableStringBuilder`, implying it copied it off my subclass.

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you avoid the recreation of your activity? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @diegoveloper Idk, it was suggested here that I shouldn't use `android:configChanges`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/4077294

Comment: it's depends of what do you need, could you put your MySpannableStringBuilderSubclass class ?